# FTP not giving permission for actions for user that has permission

Tags: users, ftp, vsftpd

I have a user on my server (Debian) that I will be using for FTP. For a given directory on the file system, he is able to create directories/create files.

```
myuser@debian-server:/storage$ su ftp_accesser
Password: 
ftp_accesser@debian-server:/storage$ echo "foobar" > foobar.txt
ftp_accesser@debian-server:/storage$ mkdir -v foobar2
mkdir: created directory 'foobar2'
ftp_accesser@debian-server:/storage$ ls -l
total 448380
drwxr-xr-x 2 root         root              4096 Mar 25 19:32 other_dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 ftp_accesser ftp_accesser      4096 Apr  9 11:32 foobar2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ftp_accesser ftp_accesser       7 Apr  9 11:31 foobar.txt

ftp_accesser@debian-server:/storage$
```

I am also running the `vsftpd` server on this server. I attempt to do the same thing as above (with the files removed, of course) using the `ftp` client.

```
Connected to localhost.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (localhost:myuser): ftp_accesser
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> cd /storage
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> mkdir foobar3
550 Permission denied.
ftp> put /home/myuser/foobar.txt foobar.txt
local: /home/myuser/foobar.txt remote: foobar.txt
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
550 Permission denied.
ftp>
```

Is there a way to allow ftp_accesser to put/mkdir files onto the server?

Comment: Have you done anything special to your vsftpd.conf? e.g. `guest_enable` or `user_config_dir`?

Comment: Have you configured `vsftp` to allow writes?  The default configuration of `vsftp` is usually `write_enable=NO` in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: "write_enable=YES" was commented out for whatever reason. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `write_enable=YES` was commented out in my `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file. Once I uncommented that and restarted the server, I was successfully able to create a directory and put a file.